# BigVideo.js .on("ended") fires multiple times

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, video.js

I'm using [BigVideo.js](http://dfcb.github.io/BigVideo.js/) jQuery plugin to show full screen background videos. I have links that load different background videos on click. At the end of each video (3-5 sec long) I'm loading an animation. Each video has its own animation on top.

Right now I'm fading in the animations with a time out that corresponds to the video length but it's not full proof. What I really need is for `#anim03` to fade in when `video-03.mp4` ends. But I can't figure out exactly how the BigVideo.js `.on("ended")` event really works. In the code I have below (simplified):

```
// init plugin
var BV = new $.BigVideo({useFlashForFirefox:false});
BV.init();

function setupVideo(url) {
  if (Modernizr.touch) {
    BV.show(url + '.jpg');
  } else {
    BV.show(url + '.mp4',{
      altSource: url + '.webm',
      ambient: false
    });
  }
}

function setupAnimation(num) {
  BV.getPlayer().on("ended", function () { // event from video.js API - when video ends playing
    $('#anim0' + num).animate({ opacity: 1 });
  });
}

$('a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  // we remove .ext cause we got to setup .webm and .jpg versions
  var url = $(this).attr('href').replace('.mp4', ''); 
  setupVideo(url);

  var current = $(this).parent().index()+1;
  setupAnimation(current);
});
```

The event is triggered but it seems to go through some sort of queue and fire multiple times. If I console.log `num` like that:

```
function setupAnimation(num) {
  console.log(num);
  BV.getPlayer().on("ended", function () {
    $('#anim0' + num).animate({ opacity: 1 });
  });
}
```

I get a single expected value. But if I do it like that:

```
function setupAnimation(num) {
  BV.getPlayer().on("ended", function () {
    console.log(num);
    $('#anim0' + num).animate({ opacity: 1 });
  });
}
```

Then I get multiple values for `num` and each time I click and this function is called, I get more and more… I'm guessing this `.on("ended")` loops through some array or something? I can't figure out that part from looking at the plugin's code.

Any help or pointer much appreciated!

Answer (score 3):

When you use the player's "on" function you register a new listener function (This gives you the possibility to trigger multiple functions when something happens).

The reason your on "ended" function fires multiple times, is because each time setupAnimation executed it adds a new instance of the listener-function:

```
function () {
    console.log(num);
    $('#anim0' + num).animate({ opacity: 1 });
}
```

check the API documentation of Video.JS
https://github.com/videojs/video.js/blob/master/docs/api/vjs.Player.md#on-type-fn-

If I get right what you're trying to accomplish, the solution is to run 'setupAnimation' outside the on 'click' function.